# Can some one point out my problem? I can't seem to print out the first element of my enum class

Tags: c#, enums

so I have this simple code which just to print out the element of the enum class:

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
  class Program
{
    public enum Mod
    {
        f1 = 3,
        f2 = 3,
        f3 = 3,
        f4 = 4,
        f5 = 4,
        f6 = 4,
        f7 = 5,
        f8 = 5
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(Mod.f1);
    }
   }
 }
```

So everytime I run this, the output is f2 not f1, but however When I try other(f2, f3, f4) the output is correct.(I'm sorry if my question is too bad but I can't seem to find the problem).

Comment: Because they have duplicated values. `Console.WriteLine(Mod.f1 == Mod.f2);` will output `True`

Comment: ok, I see it now, thank you.

Comment: The question is why did you give them the same values ?

Comment: I'm playing around with new things, I just start learning prog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the element is duplicate, thank you cid for pointing this out for me, the question is solved